# Unable to load certificates to node-pre-gyp

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install all the dependencies for one of my application using the following commands:

```
     sh 'npm config set registry artifactory.com/myCompanyPrivateRepo'
     sh 'npm config set cafile someLocaPath/cert.pem'
     sh 'npm install' 
     sh 'npm run bootstrap
```

The bootstrap command fails with the following error:

```
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.14.1/node-v12.14.1-headers.tar.gz
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp verb command remove [ '12.14.1' ]
gyp verb remove using node-gyp dir: /home/jenkins/.cache/node-gyp
gyp verb remove removing target version: 12.14.1
gyp verb remove removing development files for version: 12.14.1
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1321:34)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:794:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:608:12)
```

However, I can tell npm is able to fetch some files from the network before this error - The issue seems to be when the gyp command comes in:

```
npm http fetch GET 200 https://artifactory.com/myCompanyPrivateRepo/reusify
```